# Format of writing unit test cases for exceptions in junit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing test cases for a Java class. It contains an exception case also where the exception is thrown when response from server is not as expected.

I am bit confused about the name of that test method.

The method is `Book updateBook(Book book);`

It throws some exception when right response is not received.

For that, I have written a unit test case. But I am not sure what format should I follow for correct naming of that test method.

Should I name it

1. `testThrowExceptionWhenResponseIsNull();`

OR

2. `shouldThrowExceptionWhenBookManagementIsNull();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would prefer

```
updateBookThrowsExceptionWhenBookManagementIsNull
```

It names which method is under test and the asserted result for which condition.

But choose a name which is fitting for you und your colleagues.